# How to convert a `Show a` into a `Text`?

Tags: string, haskell

a `Show a` can be converted into a `String` with `show`. Is it possible to convert directly from a `Show a` into a `Text` without going through `String`?

I learned the best practice is to avoid `String` as much as possible. But the `Show a` typeclass seems so common that the `String` is too hard to avoid to me?

Also is there a typeclass, something like `TextShow`, such that deriving from `TextShow` will automatically get `textShow :: TextShow a => a -> Text` for free?

Comment: No, since `show` itself returns a string, and might do string processing (`map`s, etc.). But you can generate such function that will work with all `Show` types.

Comment: There are some projects like [text-show](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-show-3.7.3/docs/TextShow.html) with `Text`-based typeclasses seeking to replace `Show`, though none that have gained widespread adoption as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `show` is a function with type [**`Show a => a -> String`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show) which means that a program can construct any function that generates a `String`. We can not automatically (with a compiler) "specialize" all functions such that it immediately returns a `Text`, although it is possible that the Haskell compiler can do some optimizations.

We can however construct our own `showText` function:

```
import Data.Text(Text, pack)

showText :: Show a => a -> Text
showText = pack . show
```

this will work for all `Show` types, and thus `pack` it into a `Text`.

Perhaps it is however possible to sometimes *optimize* the `ShowText` by a programmer (for example return `Text` constants is typically better than using a `pack`). We can define a type class, with a default implementation for `Show`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

import Data.Text(Text, pack)

class ShowText a where
    showText :: a -> Text

    default showText :: Show a => a -> Text
    showText = pack . show
```

So if we make an instance of `ShowText` and the type is a `Show` type, then if we implement a specific function, that function will be used, if we do not do this, then the default "fallback" implementation will be used.

Comment: If you use strict text instead of `Builder`, aren't you apt to get even worse performance than `ShowS` when you start composing these?

Comment: @ChrisMartin: well that depends on how we compose this. A `Builder` is not a `Text`, but indeed we might also add a way to work with a `Builder`, and convert the end product into a `Text`, such that we have more tools to combine parts into larger strings.